# How to group WHERE clauses with active record?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

The below active record code isn't grouping WHERE clauses like I need it to...

```
        $this->db->where('customers_id',$this->user->getCurrentUserProperty('id'))
        $this->db->like('delivery_name', $this->input->post('search'));
        $this->db->or_like('customers_company', $this->input->post('search'));
        $this->db->or_like('customers_company2', $this->input->post('search'));
        $this->db->or_like('customers_company3', $this->input->post('search'));
        $this->db->or_like('customers_company4', $this->input->post('search'));
```

This generates

```
WHERE `customers_id` = 31509 AND `delivery_name` LIKE '%str%' OR `customers_company` LIKE '%str%'"
```

I NEED the output to have parenthesis around it like below... how can I do that?

```
WHERE `customers_id` = 31509 AND (`delivery_name` LIKE '%str%' OR `customers_company` LIKE '%str%')"
```

Note: I hate active record for annoying times like this

If I use the below method, how can I sanitize the input so it's not raw into the query?

```
$where = "name='Joe' AND status='boss' OR status='active'";

$this->db->where($where);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a clean way to do this.  `where` accepts a string to be used as the clause, so you can do something like this (yes I know, it's not pretty):

```
$search = $this->db->escape_like_str($this->input->post('search'));
$this->db->where('customers_id',$this->user->getCurrentUserProperty('id'));
$this->db->where("(`delivery_name` LIKE '%$search%' OR `customers_company` LIKE '%$search%')");
```

Answer (score 1):

In Codeigniter 3.0.3 you can do it simple like this :

```
$this->db->where('customers_id',$this->user->getCurrentUserProperty('id'));
$this->db->group_start();
$this->db->like('delivery_name', $this->input->post('search'));
$this->db->or_like('customers_company', $this->input->post('search'));
$this->db->or_like('customers_company2', $this->input->post('search'));
$this->db->or_like('customers_company3', $this->input->post('search'));
$this->db->or_like('customers_company4', $this->input->post('search'));
$this->db->group_end();
```

Perhaps it can help

Comment: actually this is the best sollution, clean, simple and can be good for other purposes